# Sending data to local service jQuery fails in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

For a project I am working on I need to send some character data from a webpage to a local service. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but does not in IE8.

The code I have:

```
var longstring = 'a very, very, very long string of 7726 characters';

alert('String size is '+longstring.length);

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:9001/MyService/ReceiveString?callback=?',
    data: { mystring: longstring },
    success: function (result) { alert('Success: ' + result); },
    error: function (result) { alert ('Error: '+result); },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
});

alert('Post done!');
```

I tested this in IE and Chrome and it works fine. All data is sent to the local service. However, when I run this from within IE, the data sent to the service is trunctated at 2880 characters.

I logged the string length in IE, and it looks ok before being sent to the service. I do not think this is an IE string size limitation.

I am using jQuery 1.8.2, and I can not find size limits in the documentation for the method I am using to post the data.

This used to be an asynchronous call and I changed it to be synchronous just to see if maybe IE cuts Javascript off in the middle of the execution, but that does not seem to be the case.

I get the "post done!" alert in all browsers.

How do I get all string data sent to my service in IE

Answer (score 0):

I see you've got *two* '?' characters in your url, not sure if this causes any problem?

Furthermore, Internet explorer has a maximum URL length of 2083 chars [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427]. This should not apply to 'post' data as this *should* be sent as header, not as part of the URL.

You might try to trace the request in Internet Explorer, to see if the data is properly sent as POST data and not as part of the URL

Comment: I removed the two ?, same result. This is a post, not a get, I am aware of those limitations. I am not sure how I can trace sent data in IE.

Comment: Weird problem then. IE is a PITA for debugging. I'm at an iMac at the moment, so I'm not able to try it. What are you using for the back-end/service? 'Fidler' might be an option to trace the traffic between the server and the browser (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), but maybe you've got additional options to debug in your backend?

Comment: The backend is a local Windows service, custom C# code. Basically it stores the string in a database. I see that not all data is getting through, it seems to get lost somewhere inside IE.

Comment: Apart from the non-standard port, I don't see any strange things in your code. You might try upgrading jQuery to 1.8.3, there are 'some' fixes for Internet Explorer and AJAX, but I don't see anything regarding your particular situation (http://blog.jquery.com/2012/11/13/jquery-1-8-3-released/). Sorry that I'm not able to help you out!